# Return Promise.resolve or just return within a promise chain

Tags: promise, es6-promise

I am little confused on some of these promises. The guy who wrote some of the code is no longer with the company. So, trying to understand why in some places he returns `Promise.resolve(data)` and in some places it just `return data`. Below is a sample promise chain and the function that is being called within the promise chain.

```
let experimentFunc = function(data) {
    if(data && data.length <= 100) {
        return Promise.resolve(data); //<- should this be Promise.resolve or can it just be return data
    } else if(data.length > 500) {
        return Promise.reject(data); //<- since we want to reject on error, this should be ok.
    } else {
        return data //<- should this be return Promise.resolve(data) or since its part of the promise chain, there is no need to do Promise.resolve, instead just return?
    }
}

Somefunc.method(data)
    .then(experimentFunc)
    .then(successResponse)
    .catch(error);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Summary:**

From within a `.then()` handler, you can do either `return someValue` or `return Promise.resolve(someValue)` with similar behavior.

From within a `.then()` handler, you can do either `throw someError` or `return Promise.reject(someError)` with similar behavior.

As a style preference, I choose `return someValue;` and `throw someError` as they seem simpler to me since neither creates another temporary promise object that isn't really needed.

---

**Longer Explanation:**

Within a promise chain from a `.then()` handler, you can just `return someValue`.  There is no need to do `return Promise.resolve(someValue)`.  It won't hurt you, but it's not necessary.

Within a `.then()` handler, you have the following options:

1. Return a plain value.
2. Return a promise that resolves in the future or is already resolved.
3. Throw an exception
4. Return a promise that rejects in the future or is  already rejected.

In #1, the promise chain advances immediately with your return value as the resolved value of the chain for the next step in the chain so `return someValue` is equivalent to `return Promise.resolve(someValue);`.

In #2 and #4, the parent promise chain will wait for the promise to reject/resolve before advancing down the promise chain if it is not already fulfilled.

In #3, the `.then()` handler you are in will catch the exception and then reject the promise chain so `throw error` inside a `.then()` handler behaves equivalently to `return Promise.reject(error);`.

---

Using your example, I would choose this style:

```
let experimentFunc = function(data) {
    if (typeof data === "object" && data.hasOwnProperty("length")) {
        if (data.length > 500) {
            throw new Error("data length too long", {cause: data});
        }
        return data;
    }
    // didn't get any data object here
    throw new Error("Missing data", {cause: data});
}

Somefunc.method(data)
    .then(experimentFunc)
    .then(successResponse)
    .catch(error);
```

Comment: Very good explanation and now its much clearer. Thank you so much.